# Quickest way to check which property inside an object holds value?

Tags: javascript, object

Probably a dumb question, Assume i have an object like below,

```
{"Country":"country","Continent":"continent","Province":"","District":"","State":"state","City":""}"
```

What is the quickest way to check which properties hold the values in the above object without using a loop?

while doing this inside a for loop is working,

```
if(typeof someUndefVar == whatever) -- works
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

Country, Continent and State

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = {"Country":"country","Continent":"continent","Province":"","District":"","State":"state","City":""};

Object.keys(a).filter( prop => a[prop] );
```

It also depends on how you want to handle the `0`, `null`, `undefined` values.

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows;

```js
var obj  = {"Country":"country","Continent":"continent","Province":"","District":"","State":"state","City":""};
for (var prop in obj) !!obj[prop] && console.log(prop);
```

Comment: can you explain the meaning of `!!obj[prop]` to me?? I am never see double `!!`

Comment: @Fadhly Permata It's basically done to convert the falsy or truthy values to their  Boolean equivalents. `"undefined"` or `""` or `0` (number) are falsy values in JS and if done like `!0` (single negate) becomes `true`. So double negate or double-bang (`!!`) puts it to it's Boolean state `!!0` is `false`. Accordingly `!!""` (double negated empty string) is `false` and the second part of `&&`  never gets executed.

Comment: ooooo... so we no need to add `()` bracket to do that? And how about triple or more negates e.g: `!!!obj[prop]`. I am sure this will be fine if I aim using `()` e.g. `!(!(!obj[prop]))`

Comment: @Fadhly Permata Although you could use parenthesis there is no need  unless you want to evaluate the combined Boolean value of a group of values. So lets assume `obj[prop] = ""` then `!obj[prop]` would be `true`, `!!obj[prop]` would be `false` and `!!!obj[prop]` would be `true` again.

Comment: OK... thank you very much dude... today my daily vote limit reached.. Tomorrow I'll Up-vote your all answer here... Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `object.keys()` function,

Like this,

```
var jsonData= {"Country":"country","Continent":"continent","Province":"","District":"","State":"state","City":""};
console.log(Object.keys(jsonData));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you said no loop and I got excited and I was bored and I got functional.

First I shortened some names and I guess they are kind of self explanatory:

- head: first element of an array
- tail: all the elements but the first
- isEmpty: check if an array has length 0

`transform` does the actual work using a callback, it stops if the keys array is empty if not goes recursive.

```
var data = {"Country":"country","Continent":"continent","Province":"","District":"","State":"state","City":""}

// plumbing
var head = (a) => a[0]
var tail = (a) => a.slice(1)
var isEmpty = (a) => a.length === 0

// actual stuff happens here
var transform = (obj, callback) => {

    var withval = (keys) => {

      if(isEmpty(keys)) return

      var p = head(keys)

      if(!!obj[p]) callback(p)

      withval(tail(keys))
    }

    withval(Object.keys(obj))
}

// Logs
var log = (p) => console.log(p)
transform(data, log)

// Array making
var arr = [];
var toArr = (p) => arr.push(p)
transform(data, toArr)
console.log(arr)

// Object making
var obj = {}
var toObj = (p) => obj[p] = data[p]
transform(data, toObj)
console.log(obj)
```

Outcome:

```
Country
Continent
State
[ 'Country', 'Continent', 'State' ]
{ Country: 'country', Continent: 'continent', State: 'state' }
```